# Test you are on a page with Cucumber and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

In [The training wheels came off](http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off) post by Aslak Hellesoy he says he has removed web_steps.rb and paths.rb from more recent versions of cucumber.

I can understand using the Capybara api instead of web_steps.rb, but how would you now test that you are on a specific page?

This is how I used to do it with paths.rb:

```
#admin_authentication.feature    
Then  I should be on the admin home page

# paths.rb
when /the admin home page/
  admin_root_path

# web_steps.rb
Then /^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  current_path = URI.parse(current_url).path
  if current_path.respond_to? :should
    current_path.should == path_to(page_name)
  else
    assert_equal path_to(page_name), current_path
  end
end
```

As a secondary question, should we be doing this at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ordinarily, you should not test the page path in a Cucumber step. Cucumber scenarios are meant to be written from the user's perspective. The user is ordinarily only interested in the page's content, so the test should check the page content rather than the particular URL or controller.

Instead of writing a scenario from the developer's perspective like this:

```
Scenario: Administrator should be on the admin home page
  When I log in as an administrator
  Then I should be on the admin home page
```

Write it from the user's perspective like this:

```
Scenario: Administrator should have super-user tools
  When I log in as an administrator
  Then I should see the disable-abusive-user button
```

Comment: I think this answer is more in keeping with the spirit of Cucumber and the training wheels article

Answer (score 13):

I simply do like this, see if it works for you:

```
assert page.current_path == admin_root_path
```

Comment: This answer did work for me, although I won't be using it because it isn't user focussed

Comment: @Paul, you was asking about Capybara and this is a Capybara code in my answer. Capybara is not "user focussed", Cucumber is. I thing you are confusing them here

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...my fault!

Comment: I used to "assert" like this but after changing my menu to work with Turbolinks this does not work. Now I'm taking a more user's perspective approach removing some of these brittle details